# disable updates on dev-master dependencies

Tags: composer-php

We have composite project with many custom and 3rd party libraries.
We are looking for a way to update most of the sub project with composer update..
but to be safe, we need to lock down all the sub dependencies to the currently installed version.

I had no problems with tagged versions, but "dev-master" gives me trouble

can a Lock a dependencies  **"some/fu" : "dev-master"**
(with current version 0.1) to stay as it is, and never update to 0.2 ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `dev-master` is a moving target. So the meaning of `dev-master` can change at any time.

Let's say that it represents the latest 1.0 development version. At some point the author of said library starts working on the `1.1` release, so they branch off a `1.0` branch, and `dev-master` becomes automatically the latest `1.1` dev version.

Technically the `dev-master` has no version it *is* a version and it represents the most current development state of the master branch.

If you have control over the source repository which you want to require you could make use of a [branch alias](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md#branch-alias).

Or you can update only specific packages like `composer update vendor/package1 vendor/package2` or to shorten it specific vendors `composer update vendor/*` instead of a full `composer update`. As far as I know there is no possibility to exclude specific packages from update yet.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Peh answer:

Yes, using `dev-master` is a bad practice. But if it is a really necessary you can pick up certain commit `"symfony/finder": "dev-master#2633721877cae79ad461f3ca06f3f77fb4fce02e"`

What scenario does lead to problems with `master` branch? when do you want execute `composer update`?

Comment: Hm yes but this sticks it to a certain commit and will *never* update. Another approach could be forking the package (and require the fork) and pick the commits you like. So you have full control over any changes/updates.

Comment: yes, i agree with you. It is a another approach with some pros and cons.